# Leaf turning brown and looking super sick

Tags: houseplants, leaf, browning

I have been taking care of this good boi called Walter for about a year now:

[image]

I am a beginner at plants and I have basically found this leaf on the street, left it in water until it developed nice roots, and potted it.

Walter has been doing great for about a year and started looking sick yesterday.

Any chance I can still save it? Any information would be appreciated :)

What I know:

- I know it came from a huge tree
- I have been watering it once a week and it was doing fine so far
- I keep it close to a plant growth lamp during winter

Comment: Looks like a fiddle-leaf fig. Those light patches are a bad sign. Hard to believe it got sick in one day. Don't recognize the illness.

Comment: The bandages made me laugh.  How dry or wet is Walter's soil?  How long have they had those brown patches?

Comment: It was dry, I usually water him once a week. The brown patches basically appeared overnight, it was totally sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE ON WALTER**

Walter is doing fine, I managed to save it :)

The lesson I wanted to share with anyone following this post, is that I pretty much heard everyone saying that Walter was dead and beyond saving ( including the person from the gardening shop )

But Walter is alive and well! Don't give up so easily on your plant babies.

Answer (score 1):

I took Walter to a gardening shop and they advised me to replace his soil with soil with some extra nutrients, keep his new soil slightly moist all the time, trim the bad parts of the leaf and basically hope for a miracle because he is in a pretty bad shape.

Now he got a new pot, new soil, nice lights, and a lot of love.

<s>savewalterwhite.com</s>

savewaltertheplant <3

[image]

Comment: That plant is certainly loved...